# Protecting certain include locations

Tags: c++, c, gcc, include, include-path

I'm building a little language that will compile to C or C++, I haven't decided yet, however I have come across a dilemma concerning the `#include` keyword.

My language will come with a standard library that will be incorporated into the language, and be accessible much like that of C or C++ with the standard includes such as `#include <string>`.

My compiler can automatically tell the difference between **user** includes and **standard library** includes, but my issue lies in how the GCC compiler uses the `-I` flag.

Let's take Java as an example. One of the default packages (folder) is called `java.util`. If I try to make my own folder called `java.util` inside my project, I get the error:

> The package java.util conflicts with a package accessible from another module: java.base

Meaning it is included by default.

I would like this to do the same thing in C++, but am worried that a user could (hypothetically) do a relative path include and cause a conflict.

Take for example, I use the flag like so: `-I ../some/folder`.

However then the user could simply type `#include "../some/folder"` to access the same content. Is there any way I can restrict this, and like the title of the question suggests, *"protect"* the folder from being called like that?

Furthermore, if there is a file inside of that folder called `test.h` and the user decides to create their own file called `test.h` locally and include it. How will the conflicts occur? Will it pick the local folder over the included via. flags?

An example of a basic implementation is as follows: (General syntax, no specific language)

```
boolean userDefine = false;
string defineName = "foo";

// Do something to determine if <> define or "" define.

if (userDefine) {
    // Returns #include "foo"
    return "#include \"" + defineName + "\"";
} else {
    // Returns #include "stdlib/foo"
    return "#include \"stdlib/" + defineName + "\"";
}
```

But then again, the user could include the folder so that it satisfies the first condition and still gain access.

Comment: If you use stock, standard-variety, ifndef/define guards, and if you have your headers always included in every robo-generated code, then someone can stick hundreds of explicit includes of your headers, and it won't make any difference, whatsoever.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ahhh! So your saying if i generate them and include them **prior** to any user includes, they will always be mo-

Comment: Oh my god this is brilliant.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I keep my questions open for 24 hours before accepting anything to attract an answer but please, I would love for you to turn your comment into an answer as I believe you may have just solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much the standard practice to put any `#include` files at the very beginning of the C++ source file, as the first order of business.

Of course, a `#include` can appear anywhere in the C++ source file, and there are situations when that happens but, if you were to grab some random C++ source from github, chances are pretty good that all the `#include` files will be at the beginning of the file.

So, all you have to do, is to make arrangements that your library's `#include` is always at the beginning, and use the standard `#ifndef/#define` guards in your header files. Then, manual inclusion of them subsequently will have no effect whatsoever, no matter what path is used.

Of course, this won't stop anyone from manually `#undef`ing your guard, to create some chaos. However, C++ never had a reputation for reliably preventing you from shooting yourself in the foot, and is unlikely to earn that reputation in the foreseeable future; so what? Actually, most compilers implement `#pragma once`, which might be a slightly better foot self-shooting prevention approach...

Comment: Well well well. I actually didn't know that an `#undef` existed but luckily since it's a new language, I can just not include that feature. ;) hehe.....

Comment: "However, C++ never had a reputation for reliably preventing you from shooting yourself in the foot" No, foot-shooting is C. C++ is about [blowing your whole leg off](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup).